# Selenium RC - Cannot redeclare class PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase

Tags: selenium-rc, php, include-path

This I have found on the net in various places but with no actual solution. The default code for running a test is

```
<?php

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . './PEAR/');
require_once 'Testing/Selenium.php';
require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php';

class GoogleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    private $selenium;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->selenium = new Testing_Selenium("*firefox", 
                                               "http://www.google.com");
        $this->selenium->start();
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        $this->selenium->stop();
    }

    public function testGoogle()
    {
        $this->selenium->open("/");
        $this->selenium->type("q", "hello world");
        $this->selenium->click("btnG");
        $this->selenium->waitForPageToLoad(10000);
        $this->assertRegExp("/Google Search/", $this->selenium->getTitle());
    }

}
?>
```

This gives me the following error

`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase in /usr/lib/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php on line 115`

My include path looks like this

`.:/usr/lib/php/ZendLatest/library/:/usr/lib/php/:./PEAR/`

Can anyone help me fix this? It isn't obvious where the class is being re-declared, is it on line 115 of the file mentioned above or somewhere else?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this by changing the line

```
 require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php';
```

To

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework.php';
```

The `Framework.php` file is the Bootstrap for PHPUnit and including this deals with all other includes. Including `TestCase.php` doesn't work because that isn't the Bootstrap file and thus doesn't load PHPUnit correctly.